# getstream.io - Is there a way to prevent activities from bouncing back to a user via another feed?

Tags: getstream-io

Say I have user who follows a football team. That user posts a message on that teams forum, which creates an activity on the teams feed. Since the user follows the team he also gets an activity in his own feed, about his own post.

Is there any way (other than filtering on the client side) to avoid user initiated activities on other feeds bouncing back on their own feeds?

The user has two feeds, his activity feed, which other users follow, and his notifications feed, which he uses to follow other feeds, such as the football teams.

As he posts on the forum the activity is added to the teams feed and his activity feed, but since the users notification feed also follows the teams feed, the user gets his own activity on his notification feed - this is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to address this is to make your activities unique, once you got that right even if the same activity lands on a feed twice, it will only appear once.

To achieve that, you only need to pass `time` and `foreign_id` fields when creating activities. For instance, you can set the `time` field to the creation time of the activity and the `foreign_id` to the ID of the object the activity refers to in your database.

You can find more information about this functionality in the documentation here: http://getstream.io/docs/#uniqueness

Note that if you use any of the framework integration (RoR, Django, Laravel, ...) you get this out of the box.

**EDIT**: Stream recently introduce configurable discard rules that allow you to ignore certain updates (eg. activities coming "back" to its author feed via a follow relationship). More information is available on the documentation: we just added something called update discard rules, https://getstream.io/docs/#discard-rules

Comment: Not really sure we're really talking about the same thing. My problem is not that I get duplicate activities on the same feed, but that a user gets his own activities from other feeds forwarded to his own feed. I'm not talking about the users own activity feed, but rather his "notification feed". That others can see that he posted on the forum on his own activity feed is fine.

When the user looks at his own notification feed it says "You posted on football X forum" which is of low interest to him since it was his own action.

Comment: You have a good point there. I think indeed the only way to achieve that right now is to filter it out client side. This is something we should think about for our roadmap though.

Comment: Thanks @Thierry - Not a blocker for me since it is fairly easy to filter client side, I just wanted to know whether I was missing out on an existing feature to handle this scenario.

Comment: Perhaps there could be something similar to the "to" option, but with the opposite intent - "notTo" would restrict a fanout to any feeds listed, such as a user notification field.

Comment: This is definitely a concern for me as well.  The problem with filtering notifications client-side is that even though you can filter out the activities, you can't filter their presence out of the unseen/unread counts. The result is you have to mark your own activities as seen & read each time you come across one. It's terribly cumbersome. 

The right solution would be that, for a notification feed with id X, to simply exclude all activities with author X.  I suppose this should be optional, so this could just be a flag on the notification feed group itself.  I would *love* to see this.

Comment: The idea from @averas of a `notTo` option isn't a bad idea either, but I would want activities to still travel to flat feeds, just not notification feeds.

Comment: @bengreene we just added something called update discard rules, http://getstream.io/docs/#discard-rules get in touch with support if you want to test it for your application

Comment: Can we please get this feature exposed somehow through the UI?  The UI has been (nicely) refreshed, but this feature still isn't actually available. Thanks,