# How can I exclude my own actions from the feed?

Tags: getstream-io

I have common feeds which users can follow and where all users activities display. Can I add a filter that will exclude my own actions from the feed?

For example: say that the feed `news:serge` (aggregated) follows the feed `tag:programming` (flat).
When serge adds an activity to a feed `tag:programming`, then he will receive the activity in its feed `news:serge` as well, but I do not want to display activities that were added by the current users himself in the news feed.

I can filter out activities on client side and not display activities if `activity.actor == current_user.id` but it's not very convenient as it will lead to sequence loss. For example, if I try to get the next 10 activities, only part of them may remain.

As far as I understood the best option for this is  https://getstream.io/docs/#discard-rules (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35378534/3419815) but I did not quite get how to use it, only in test mode via support service?

Answer (score 2):

This is a setting that we can enable for you, we only need to know the name of the aggregated feed where you'd like that rule enabled.